# How to parse JSON into relational format in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I have some Json stored in SQL Server 2016 table as under (partitial)

```
{
  "AFP": [
    {
      "AGREEMENTID": "29040400001330",
      "LoanAccounts": {
        "Product": "OD003",
        "BUCKET": 0,
        "ZONE": "MUMBAI ZONE",
        "Region": "MUMBAI METRO-CENTRAL REGION",
        "STATE": "GOA",
        "Year": 2017,
        "Month": 10,
        "Day": 13
      },
      "FeedbackInfo": {
        "FeedbackDate": "2017-10-13T12:07:44.2317198",
        "DispositionDate": "2017-10-13T12:07:44.2317198",
        "DispositionCode": "PR"
      },
      "PaymentInfo": {
        "ReceiptNo": "2000000170",
        "ReceiptDate": "2017-10-13T12:07:42.1218299",
        "PaymentMode": "Cheque",
        "Amount": 200,
        "PaymentStatus": "CollectionBatchCreated"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

table schema as under

```
create table tblHistoricalDataDemo(
AGREEMENTID nvarchar(40)
,Year_Json nvarchar(4000)
)
```

I would like to fetch the records from JSON into relational format as

**AgreementID Product Bucket .... PaymentStatus**

I tried with below but something wrong i am doing for which I am not able to get the result

```
SELECT AGREEMENTID, 
  JSON_VALUE(Year_Json, '$.LoanAccounts') AS records
FROM tblHistoricalDataDemo
```

Comment: I think you need `OPENJSON()`, not `JSON_VALUE()`. [See the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) built in table value function:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblHistoricalDataDemo
CROSS APPLY 
    OPENJSON(Year_Json, '$.AFP') WITH
    (
    -- You don't have to specify the json path
    -- if the column name is the same as the json name
        AGREEMENTID bigint 
    )
 As afp
 CROSS APPLY 
    OPENJSON(Year_Json, '$.AFP') WITH
    (
        Product varchar(10) '$.LoanAccounts.Product', 
        bucket int '$.LoanAccounts.BUCKET'
    )
 As LoanAccounts
```

Comment: But i am getting the below error  Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar Are you sure you are using SQL Server 2016 and that the compatibility level is 130?

Comment: Sorry, I've had a small mistake since I've written the code directly here. I've now edited it and tested on my SQL Server and it seems to be producing the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

In case the array in JSON has a fixed number of element, use

```
$.P1[x]
```

If AFP has only 1 element,

```
SELECT t.AGREEMENTID, 
JSON_Value(Year_Json, '$.AFP[0].LoanAccounts.Product') Product,
JSON_Value(Year_Json, '$.AFP[0].LoanAccounts.BUCKET') Bucket, 
JSON_Value(Year_Json, '$.AFP[0].PaymentInfo.PaymentStatus') PaymentStatus
FROM tblHistoricalDataDemo t
```

Run it in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/87c1f/14), thx Jacob H.